# Unable to understand linked list (c)

Tags: c, linked-list

I cant understand how linked list work.

Lets say i have some code

```
typedef struct trip {
    int id, year, something;
    char name[100], destination[100];
    struct trip *next;                       //X1

}TRIP;                                       //X2
    FILE *fr;
    TRIP *p_a, *p_p;                         //X3
    fr =fopen("list.txt","r");
    int j=0;
    p_p = (TRIP *) malloc(sizeof(TRIP));
    p_a = p_p;
    while ((fscanf(fr,"%d",&p_a->id)), p_a->id>0 )
    {
            fscanf(fr,"%s",&p_a->name);
            fscanf(fr,"%s",&p_a->destination);
            fscanf(fr,"%d",&p_a->year);
            fscanf(fr,"%d",&p_a->something);
            p_a->next = (TRIP *) malloc(sizeof(TRIP));
            p_a = p_a->next;

    }
    p_a->next = NULL;                        //X4
    fclose(fr);
    return p_p;
}
```

I am not sure what some lines do. Those lines are commented with x1 x2 x3 x4.
Please can somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**x1**

> struct trip *next;                       //X1

Inside a "trip" data structure, it contains a pointer to a another trip data structure.

You can use this to "link" elements for the linked list by having it point to another structure.

**x2**

> }TRIP;                                       //X2

This will (I forget the appropriate word) alias the structure. TRIP = trip.

This is to say

```
trip a; // OR
TRIP a;
```

Would both be valid

**x3**

> TRIP *p_a, *p_p;                         //X3

This is declaring two variables, p_a, p_p, of type *TRIP ** (or *trip **, they're equivalent)

This type is a pointer to a trip data structure.

**x4**

> p_a->next = NULL;                        //X4

This is member selection in a pointer. That is to say, it now sets the value of the "next" element in the trip structure pointed to by p_a is equal to NULL.

If it would be of help, it would be equivalent to

```
(*p_a).next = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct trip {                       
    int id, year, something;
    char name[100], destination[100];
    struct trip *next;                   //Define a pointer to a trip struct
                                         //called next. This will hold a
                                         //pointer to the next element in
                                         //the list.

}TRIP;                                   //The name of the typedef statement
                                         //After this you can define a trip 
                                         //without writing 'struct trip' but 
                                         //just 'TRIP'

FILE *fr;
TRIP *p_a, *p_p;                         //Define two pointers to trip structs
fr =fopen("list.txt","r");
int j=0;
p_p = (TRIP *) malloc(sizeof(TRIP));
p_a = p_p;
while ((fscanf(fr,"%d",&p_a->id)), p_a->id>0 )
{
        fscanf(fr,"%s",&p_a->name);
        fscanf(fr,"%s",&p_a->destination);
        fscanf(fr,"%d",&p_a->year);
        fscanf(fr,"%d",&p_a->something);
        p_a->next = (TRIP *) malloc(sizeof(TRIP));
        p_a = p_a->next;

}
p_a->next = NULL;                        //After the last line has been added
                                         //to the list, end the list by making
                                         //the next pointer NULL
fclose(fr);
return p_p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

x1: `next` is a pointer to another instance of `struct trip`.  A picture might help:

```
+-------+------+       +-------+------+       +-------+------+
| stuff | next | ----> | stuff | next | ----> | stuff | next | ----|||
+-------+------+       +-------+------+       +-------+------+
```

where `stuff` is all the other data you're storing in that node (`id`, `year`, `something`, `name`, `destination`).  The `next` member stores the address of another node.

C allows you to declare pointers to a `struct` type within that `struct` type's definition:

```
struct foo {
  ...
  struct foo *fooptr;
  ...
};
```

You don't need to know the size of the `struct` type in order to create a pointer to it, and pointers to all `struct` types have the same size and representation.  That is, a pointer to `struct foo` has the same size as a pointer to `struct bar`, even though `struct foo` and `struct bar` may have radically different definitions.

x2: The `typedef` facility allows you to create aliases for types - `TRIP` is an alias for the type name `struct trip`.  This is useful if you want to simplify a complex type or abstract away implementation details (the `FILE` typedef name in `stdio.h` is an example of the latter).

x3: This line declares `p_a` and `p_p` as pointers to `struct trip`.